# nodejs async code entering seemingly false condition

Tags: node.js, async-await, conditional-statements

EDIT
My program is still entering inside a code area when if condition false.
(uses: nodejs, mongoose).
I've boiled down the code to its simplest expression and the problem remains.
I'm still entering into the **if(latestOnly)** area when **latestOnly is false:**

```js
const singleProdListCompat = async (prodId, latestOnly = false) => {
    console.log("1 latestOnly=", latestOnly);
      let _prodList = [];
      const _list = await V2v.find({ axProductVersion: prodId })
        .cursor()
        .eachAsync(async (v2v) => {
          if (latestOnly) {
            console.log("2 XXXXXXXXXXXXX inside if (latestOnly), latestOnly=", latestOnly);
          } 
        });
      return _prodList;
    };
```

Here's the output.

```
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXX inside if (latestOnly), latestOnly= false
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXX inside if (latestOnly), latestOnly= false
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXX inside if (latestOnly), latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXX inside if (latestOnly), latestOnly= false
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXX inside if (latestOnly), latestOnly= false
1 latestOnly= false
entering  /api/product/compat/:id/api/product/compatList/:latest true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXX inside if (latestOnly), latestOnly= true
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXX inside if (latestOnly), latestOnly= true
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXX inside if (latestOnly), latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXX inside if (latestOnly), latestOnly= true
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXX inside if (latestOnly), latestOnly= true
1 latestOnly= true
```

OLDER VERSION:
My program seems to be entering inside a code area when if condition false.
(uses: nodejs, mongoose)

```js
const singleProdListCompat= async (prodId, latestOnly=false)=> {
    let _prodList = []
    const _list = await V2v.find({axProductVersion: prodId })
        .cursor()
        .eachAsync( async (v2v) => {
            let _p
             _p = await Product.findOne({_id : v2v.extProductVersion })
             console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxxx  singleProdListCompat, latestOnly", latestOnly)
// THIS IS THE WEIRD PART
             if (latestOnly) {  // ENTERING HERE EVEN WHEN latestOnly is FALSE
                 const _latest = await latestVersionIdOfProduct(prodId)
                 if (_latest) 
                    v2v.versionPairs.findIndex((vp) => {
                        if ( vp.v1._id.toString() === _latest.toString() 
                            && vp.value === 2 
                            && vp.v2.status === "VALID")
                            { 
// SHOULD ONLY BE HERE IF latestOnly is TRUE, RIGHT?
                               console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXX TRUE vp.v1.name", vp.v1.name)
                               console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXX TRUE vp.v2.name", vp.v2.name)
                                _prodList.push(_p.name)}
                    }) 
                }
             else
            {
                console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXX FALSE _p.name", _p.name)
                ....
        }   );
    // const _prodList = await Product.find({"_id" : { $in: _list.extProductVersion}})
    // console.log("singleProdListCompat", _prodList) // OK OK OK OK OK OK OK 
    return _prodList
}
```

Here is an example of the output. latestOnly is false, yet the code seems to be entering into the area where it should be true

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxx  singleProdListCompat, latestOnly false
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  7.7
XXXXXXXXXXXXX TRUE vp.v1.name 7.7
XXXXXXXXXXXXX TRUE vp.v2.name latest on///Win XP
XXXXXXXXXXXXX TRUE vp.v1.name 7.7
XXXXXXXXXXXXX TRUE vp.v2.name latest on///Win 10///x86-64
...
```

Comment: how u call singleProdListCompat?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial await singleProdListCompat is called twice, once with latestOnly=false and once with latestOnly=true

Comment: what if both times false? I'm asking because I am wondering where `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  7.7` come from

Comment: Can you show us how you call that function ?

Comment: you probably used `"false"` instead of `false` when you call the function. There's a difference between boolean and string. This error could come from where you called `singleProdListCompat` which may have retrieved these values from database, and they consist of "false" instead of false

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial that was it! I was calling the function with the parameter from the API call, that gives a string rather than a boolean :
router.get("/api/product/compatList/:latest", async (req, res) => {
  const _latest = req.params.latest;
...
const _prodCompatObjList = await prodCompatObjList(_latest);

Comment: now you understand why it's important to show more *related* codes for us to help you quickly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I was calling the function with a string rather than the boolean.
The function was called from an API get statement:

```
router.get("/api/product/compatList/:latest", async (req, res) => { 
const _latest = req.params.latest; 
... 
const _prodCompatObjList = await prodCompatObjList(_latest);
```

after which `prodCompatObjList` calls `singleProdListCompat`

Thank you @Someonespecial for suggesting this.